# Is This a Bitcoin Scam?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, fraud

Is this a bitcoin scam? He is not asking for my username and is having me change my password before sending him the link to my mining wallet.

A bitcoin miner on LinkedIn wants to mine for me.

He asked me to set up a blockchain account and follow these instructions.

1. Click on REQUEST, you will see your mining wallet address there, Copy it and paste here or screenshot it and send here.
2. Change the Default password.
   Click on Security Centre, then Click on Advance, you will see Change Password. then use any password of your choice. You are to change only the first change password you will see.
   Follow the above steps and complete them and notify me when done so we can determine your mining hash power rate so that mining can start immediately.

Login using the Default password below.
Password: @miningserver2

Next, in that the same email you received from blockchain, open the message, under it you will see your Wallet I'd there (its a long combination of number and alphabet). Click on the wallet ID link, it will redirect you to blockchain login page.

Check your email, you will see a message from Blockchain , open the message and verify the message you got from blockchain by clicking on the verification link

Your details has been successfully registered

Comment: This is definitely, obviously a scam.

Answer (score 0):

Always be watchful for any promise that you will receive bitcoins by creating an account or any other thing. Bitcoin is money and like real money, it is not easily given. In the crypto world, unfortunately, there are a lot of scammers, be aware.